# Link List: insert a node using Recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I am wondering, how does the following two pieces of code do the same job of inserting an new node into a link list?

[verison1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRxuK.png)

[version2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aveaC.png)

In Version1, there is a `prev` pointer that can wind the previous node to the new node.

But I don't see that in Version2. In version 2, the previous link is broken (i.e., it doesn't link to the new node), am I missing something?

Comment: who upvotes something like that?

Comment: You should really post your source code here, instead of screenshots of your source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's dig into your version2 insertion:

```
void RecInsertSorted(Entry*& list, Entry* newOne) {
    if (list == nullptr || newOne->name < list->name) {
        newOne->next = list;
        list = newOne;
    else {
        RecInsertSorted(list->next, newOne);
    }
}
```

You do not need a `prev` since the work is carried out by the call. Why is that? Because the `list` parameter is a reference to a pointer.

Let's suppose we insert `newOne` between the first and the second element. At the end you want your list to look like:

> element1 -> newOne -> element2

When the condition `newOne->name < list->name` is met, `list` refers to element2. But this is a reference to a pointer, the reference refers to element1->next! Thus when the statement `list = newOne;` runs, it updates `element1->next` accordingly and your list is well formed.

Similarly, when inserting `newOne` at the end, `list` is `nullptr`. But again, it's a reference, so `newOne->next` becomes `nullptr` and `newOne` becomes the end of the list.

Again, if `newOne` has to be inserted before the first element, it updates some `head` pointer you keep to track the head of your list... therefore becoming the first element of your list.